# Why to use slug field in mongodb document?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, slug

I tried to create category hierarchy.So,I refer this link (https://docs.mongodb.com/ecosystem/use-cases/category-hierarchy/) link given number example how to create category hierarchy .but I have a doubt I this example is used **slug** field.why to use slug I could not understand can you please give solution.

**Example Document**

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("4f5ec858eb03303a11000002"),
  "name" : "Modal Jazz",
  "parent" : ObjectId("4f5ec858eb03303a11000001"),
  "slug" : "modal-jazz",
  "ancestors" : [
         { "_id" : ObjectId("4f5ec858eb03303a11000001"),
        "slug" : "bop",
        "name" : "Bop" },
         { "_id" : ObjectId("4f5ec858eb03303a11000000"),
           "slug" : "ragtime",
           "name" : "Ragtime" } ]
}
```

- what is slug ?
- Which purpose using in document ?
- why to use slug field ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Slug field is URL shortcut to get document or sub/document is simple way. 
Slug is used in document to make easy get document from URL

For example, typing `http://**host**/modal-jazz` you should get document that has "modal-jazz" as 'slug'.

I hope i helped you a bit.